# Tool to transcode Canon PF24 MTS files to native 24p?

Tags: camcorder, canon, avchd

Many Canon AVCHD camcorders record 24fps in a format they call PF24, which essentially disguises the 24 fps in a 60i stream by applying 3:2 pulldown.

Unfortunately they do this so well that to my knowledge editors can't detect it automatically and apply the reverse transformation. I have verified that this is true for Sony Vegas Pro 10 on Windows and FCPX on OS X, which treat these files as regular 60i material. When these clips are added to a 24p timeline they get the regular deinterlacing treatment, which looks awful.

Are there any tools (command line preferred) that can take a .MTS file with PF24 material and perform the inverse telecine process to convert to native 24p with minimal quality loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual tool recommended for this is JES Deinterlacer, which apparently has an adaptive method of finding and removing the 'smear' frames. I haven't used it myself.

The reason this is an issue is that the field cadence used for PF24 is (stupidly, IMO) different from the typical telecine cadence, which is what most 'inverse telecine' algos detect and remove. So applying standard inverse telecine just adds another layer of mess-up to the video.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try, though unfortunately it seems this tool does not read .mts files but QuickTime files, which will add an additional step to the process. But if it works well, I guess I'll live with it!